# implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'

Tags: android

Problem on Sync

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

On Migrating my Project to AndroidX ,error started arrising in all the java Files , created before

Comment: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate#migrate

Comment: which error? . .

Comment: not resolving so many symbols like V7 in import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; and many other symbols